# How to open Web page in Fullscreen mode (F11 functionality) on body load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building a web application and I’m want to our web application open on fullscreen in browser by default
I want, as our application run on browser at the same time it will open in full screen mode.
I’m getting output on button click but this is not working on onload event of body.

Javascript Code:

```
<script>
    function show() {
        var elem = document.body;
        if ((document.fullScreenElement !== undefined && document.fullScreenElement === null) || (document.msFullscreenElement !== undefined && document.msFullscreenElement === null) || (document.mozFullScreen !== undefined && !document.mozFullScreen) || (document.webkitIsFullScreen !== undefined && !document.webkitIsFullScreen)) {
            if (elem.requestFullScreen) {
                elem.requestFullScreen();
            } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
                elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
            } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
                elem.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
            } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
                elem.msRequestFullscreen();
            }
        } else {
            if (document.cancelFullScreen) {
                document.cancelFullScreen();
            } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
                document.mozCancelFullScreen();
            } else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
                document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
            } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
                document.msExitFullscreen();
            }
        }

    }
</script>
```

HTML Code:
This is working

```
<input type="button" value="click to toggle fullscreen" onclick="show()">
```

But this is not working

```
<body onload="show()">
```

Please help me how can I achieve this.
Thanks.

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: no error is coming and also the output is not coming

Answer (score 2):

It's not allowed to start the full screen mode without any user-interaction.

Comment: Which is a good thing. Imagine all the full-screen advertisements you would get, which wouldn't be closable.. Yikes.

Comment: Thanks. How can I achieve this. Please let me know if there is any another mechanism and library to do this.

Comment: You need some form of user interaction. Which can be a click or a keypress.

Answer (score 0):

FullScreen mode requires user interaction. When a user fires any event (i.e. click, keypress, keydown) then your window can go to fullscreen.

If you have that option that you'll be able to manage that interaction then you can go with [***jQuery fullScreen plugin***](http://plugins.jquery.com/fullscreen/)

*Try this way : [Using user interaction]*

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Test iframe</title>
    // load jQuery
    <script src="./jquery-fullscreen-plugin-master/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    // load jquery fullscreen plugin
    <script src="./jquery-fullscreen-plugin-master/jquery.fullscreen-min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#fullscreenButton").on("click", function(){
                $("body").fullScreen(true);
            });
        });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body style="background:white">
    <button id="fullscreenButton">Go to FullScreen Mode</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

There's another way which is close to your scenario. But for that you have to let malicious script (auto fullscreen in your case) allowed in your browser.

***javaScript :***

```
var height = window.screen.availHeight;
var width = window.screen.availWidth;

for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    window.open ("http://www.google.com/","","fullscreen=yes, width=" + width + ", height=" + height + "");
}
```

The following script will open new window in fullscreen mode. But first time it'll as for your permission to allow popups from your site. If you allow those it'll always execute next time until it is blocked again.

So what is happening here is you are getting the resolution of your device and open the window with the appropriate height and width.

[***jsFiddle - window.open()***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/2bv8er9d/)